# Kivy: config.ini [Input] section: My touchscreen settings don't apply

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, input-device

I am trying to use an Elo Touch monitor to work with kivy. At first i calibrated the monitor with xCalibration wich worked fine:

```
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface" id=6
    current calibration values (from XInput): min_x=315, max_x=3699 and min_y=3627, max_y=459

Doing dynamic recalibration:
    Setting new calibration data: 309, 3686, 3641, 457


--> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf'
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface"
    Option  "Calibration"   "309 3686 3641 457"
EndSection
```

Now I am trying to set up the Touchdisplay for Kivy. 
Touch seemed to be working, but on the lower screen there was some kind of offset.

I think I need to change the setting in the kivy/config.ini at [input].

I changed it to this:

```
[input:]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput, min_abs_x=300,max_abs_x=3000,min_abs_y=3636,max_abs_y=472
```

My Problem is now, that these changes don't apply. While i start my Kivy App the logger tells me:

[image]

```
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface>
```

And most important:

```
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface> range ABS Y position is 184 - 3932
```

What am I doing wrong and why wont my changes apply to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying your changes to root?

```
sudo cp ~/.kivy/config.ini /root/.kivy/config.ini
```